# How to find certain letters in array elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, how can I find elements of an array that contain certain letters?

For example, how can I define `find` in the below to match `super` and `phone` but not `wood`?

```
var array1 = ["super", "phone", "wood"]
find("h", "n", "e")

message.channel.send(results) // should send phone
```

Im doing this on discord.js and fairly new

Comment: So, what exactly are the criteria here? Should the word contain all the letters? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
function find(...letters){
  var words = ["super", "phone", "wood"]
  return words.filter(w => letters.every(l => w.includes(l)));
}


console.log(find("h", "n", "e"));
console.log(find("s", "u"));
console.log(find("o"));
```

Note that this returns an array, in case multiple matches are found.

Comment: is there a way to make it search letters by the order of the letters given
ex. var words = ["yeux" , "eyes"] and when I console.log(find("e", "y")) it shows eyes only because only eyes has the e y in that order? Thanks for the help!